# Spring Cloud Config Server: Listen for ApplicationFailedEvent when invalid Yaml config file throws a ParserException

Tags: spring, server, cloud, config

I am trying to listen for ApplicationFailedEvent when Spring Cloud Config Server fails to parse our YAML config file. I would like to raise an application alarm when this occurs. I have registered for all ApplicationFailedEvent types using the Annotation:

```
@Component
public class ApplicationFailedEventListener {
    private static final Logger LOGGER =
        LoggerFactory.getLogger( ApplicationFailedEventListener.class );

    @EventListener
    public void handleContextRefreshEvent( ContextStartedEvent ctxStartEvt) {
        System.out.println("Context Start Event received.");
    }

    @EventListener( ApplicationFailedEvent.class )
    public void handleApplicationFailedEvent( ApplicationFailedEvent event ) {
        LOGGER.info( "Received event: {}", event );
    }

}
```

and using interface

```
public class SpringBuiltInEventsListener implements ApplicationListener<SpringApplicationEvent>,
    ApplicationContextAware {
...
}
```

and add the listeners to the SprintApplication:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableConfigServer
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableTask
public class SpringCloudConfigServerApplication {
    private static final Logger LOGGER =
        LoggerFactory.getLogger( SpringCloudConfigServerApplication.class );

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        SpringApplication springApplication =
            new SpringApplication( SpringCloudConfigServerApplication.class );
        springApplication.addListeners(( ApplicationFailedEvent event)->{
            System.out.println("Executing ApplicationFailedEvent...");
        });
        springApplication.addListeners( new CustomEventHandler() );
        springApplication.addListeners(new SpringBuiltInEventsListener());
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = springApplication.run( args );
    }
}
```

but my listener never gets called with the ApplicationFailedEvent. It does get called for all the other SpringApplicationEvent s.

What do I have to do to process the ApplicationFailedEvent that Spring Cloud Config Server is sending? It seems that when it sends it the list of listeners is empty in SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent()???

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a way to get the Yaml ParseException without using ApplicationFailedEvent.

Create your own custom SpringApplicationRunListener:

```
public class CustomSpringApplicationRunListener
    implements SpringApplicationRunListener {
    private static final Logger LOGGER =
        LoggerFactory.getLogger( CustomSpringApplicationRunListener.class );

    public CustomSpringApplicationRunListener( SpringApplication application,
        String[] args ) {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void failed( ConfigurableApplicationContext context,
        Throwable exception ) {
        LOGGER.info( "Received exception: {}", exception.getMessage() );
        LOGGER.info( "Received exception cause: {}",
            exception.getCause().getMessage() );
    }
}
```

Nothing to do in main()

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableConfigServer
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class SpringCloudConfigServerApplication {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        SpringApplication.run( SpringCloudConfigServerApplication.class, args );
    }

}
```

Create file META-INF/spring.factories in resources and add the below:

```
org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListener=com.springcloudconfigserver.CustomSpringApplicationRunListener
```

Now I get called with the actual exception and I can raise an alarm with the detailed parsing error information.